# How to grep file to find lines like <version>1.1.9-beta</version>?

Tags: regex, grep, sh

Looking for suggestion to `cat file | grep REGEX` to get the lines with `<version>anything</version>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -F '<version>1.1.9-beta</version>' file
```

- `-F` will match your pattern as literal text
- you don't need that useless `cat`
- if you really mean `anything`: try `grep '<version>.*</version>' file` or `grep -P '<version>.*?</version>' file` , however **searching xml with regex is bad idea**.

Answer (score 1):

Use the -E option to match a regular expression:

```
grep -E "<version>.*</version>" file
```

Refer to these rules for the regular expression: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions

For example, to match the typical version format (3.14, or 13.14, or 0.1458) you can type:

```
grep -E "<version>[0-9]?\.[0-9]?</version>" file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
grep '<version>[^<]*</version>' file.xml
```

`[^<]*` will match zero or more characters upto next `<`.