# Grep: How to extract version string between these tags: <version>1.1.9-beta</version>

Tags: regex, grep, sh

I would like to extract the version number between these tags using command line regex:

```
$ cat file.xml
<version>1.0-beta</version>

# example of solution
$ grep regex file.xml  
1.0-beta
```

Comment: Note that `grep` does only in-line matches, but in general, it is not safe to assume that XML element content will be without line breaks, even if it contains only text.  Leading and/or trailing whitespace, including line breaks, is relatively common.  Possibly you don't have to worry about that in your particular data, but that seems a somewhat precarious assumption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep file to find lines like <version>1.1.9-beta</version>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453067/how-to-grep-file-to-find-lines-like-version1-1-9-beta-version)

Comment: This question is different. Here we extract the version number without the tag. In the other question the goal was to `grep` the whole string including the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '<version>\K[^<]+(?=</version>)' file.xml
```

**Example:**

```
$ grep -Po '<version>\K[^<]+(?=</version>)' <<<'<version>1.0-beta</version>'
1.0-beta
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
\<version\>(.*?)\</version\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk command that will work on BSD or non-GNU versions as well:

```
awk -F '</?version>' '{print $2}' file

1.0-beta
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need something that works for **any** tag :

```
grep -Po "(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<)" file.xml
```

### <kbd>[**Live demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/fJ1aJ0/1)</kbd>

**Explanation :**

`-P` : interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression (PCRE), this is needed because we use lookarounds

`-o` : print only what is matched by the pattern, multiple matches are separated by a new line

`(?<=>)` : positive lookbehind which match `>`

`[^<>]*` : character class which match any character but not `<` nor `>`, `*` means 0 or more times

`(?=<)` : positive lookahead which match `<`